How to change the hash value of two Audio files
I recently uploaded my song on ST digital Music distribution company. ...when i went for another Audio file,, I filled up all the details about the audio file and in the next column I uploaded my Audio track in "WAVE" format...after completing the upload the system shows " (a file with the same Hash value already exists in the systems) " and the upload failed...
I tried to uploaded an audio file,,
I expected the release of my 2nd song...
But the upload failed because of the same HASH value in both 2 song

If it is the same hash, that means it is the same song. If you modify your audio file, you will get a new hash, but I don't think that is what you want to do.
